# How to get data from a method which relies on other methods for its data?

Tags: java, list, methods, parameter-passing

I have three methods.

1. The first method takes data from a List (which contains data objects specific to our my application), it then calls the second method, passing in the data it has acquired as parameters.
2. The second method then uses this information as a reference to take specific information from another list, calling the third method and passing this information to it as parameters.
3. The third method does the same as the second, using the data that is passed in as a reference to find specific data in a list.

Now the problem is, I want to use this information in a totally different method.

How should I go about calling my methods in order to get out the data?

```
private void getRecords() {
    List<LabelSet> allSets = labelSetStructureService.getLabelSets();
    for (LabelSet labelSet : allSets) {
        List<LabelSet> groups = labelSetStructureService.getLabelGroupsForSet(labelSet.getId());
        for (LabelGroup group : groups) {
             getValuesForLabel(group.getCustomerMeasure(), labelSetStructureService.getLabelsForLabelGroup(group.getCustomer().getId(), group.getId()), labelSet);
        }
    }
}

private void getValuesForLabel(CustomerMeasure measure, List<Label> labels, LabelSet labelSet) {
    for (Label label : labels) {
        List<LabelSet> usageRecs = labelDataService.getLabelData(label, LabelSetStorage.DAY_BY_MONTH_STORAGE, new DateTime(), new DateTime().minusWeeks(1));
        preProcessUsageRecs( usageRecs, labelSet);
    }
}

private List<LabelUsage> preProcessUsageRecs(List<LabelUsage> usageRecs, LabelSet labelSet) {
    //Format records, use list instead strings where possible

    List<LabelSet> usageRecords = usageRecs; {
      for( LabelUsage labelUsage : usageRecs)
          usageRecords.addAll(usageRecs);
    }
     return usageRecords;
    }
```

Comment: further explanation is needed

Comment: If there's not too much code, then that would be nice to see aswell

Comment: Pass everything back up through return statements?

Comment: is the new method (totally different method) in the same class as others ?? IF i understand correctly you just wanna use the information obtained in your 3rd method, so why cant you have an instance variable and save that information later you can use it in your "totally different method".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is an object based language, so use a member variable to store the result of that one call, like such that:

```
public List<LabelUsage> labels;
...
private List<LabelUsage> preProcessUsageRecs(List<LabelUsage> usageRecs, LabelSet labelSet) {
    //Format records, use list instead strings where possible

    List<LabelSet> usageRecords = usageRecs; {
      for( LabelUsage labelUsage : usageRecs)
          usageRecords.addAll(usageRecs);
    }
    this.labels = usageRecords;
     return usageRecords;
}
```

and then access `this.labels` wherever you would need to use the result of this method;

Comment: An instance member (or a class member - static) is sometimes inappropriate (or incorrect) for maintaining data consistency - specifically in a multi-user environment like a web.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me! sometimes the simple solutions are the ones you dont think of!!

Comment: @Lion: Can you explain that to me?

Comment: I'm only talking about **some situations** where using some variables or objects as instance members can lead to data inconsistency. Regarding the Servlet container - it is initialized only once when it is loaded and then onwards it is shared among every request. Therefore placing *request* or *session* scoped data as Servlet instance members are shared among every request leading to the data inconsistency state which may or may not be the case of this question (where the OP is using this code is undefined though it looks obvious that it's a stand-alone application).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are writing some suspect code.  Based on your description it sounds like your API should look something like this if I understand the problem:

```
public void go(Map<MapKey,Collection<MyObject>> values, Keyword keyword)  
{  
      for(MapKey key: values.keyset())  
     {  
                 search(values.get(key),keyword);
     }  
}  

public void search(Collection<MyObject> searchSpace, Keyword key)  
{  
       for(MyObject currentSearch : searchSpace)  
       {  
            if(currentSearch == key)  
            {  
                //do something
            }  
       }  
}
```

The point is you should be able to generalize the search into one function, if something special needs to happen you can apply some private (helper) functions to this process and bind them via a switch statement.